# Regex expression to check if string obeys certain conditions

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a python function that takes a string, and uses REGEX to check if the string contains:

1. At least 1 uppercase letter;
2. At least 2 numerical digits;
3. Exactly 2 special characters, !@#$&*-_.
4. A length of 6-8 characters;

Returns true if these exist and false otherwise. I'm good with the function, however, I'm having trouble with the regular expression.

What I have so far is: `[A-Z]+\d{2,}[!@#\$&\*-_\.]{2}`

I know this doesn't work, I'm really confused since I'm new to regex.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have to put all those conditions into a single regex?  Or can you break it into one regex for each condition?

Comment: Are you trying to do it to check for password requirement?

Comment: @John Gordon Nope they don't all have to be in a single regex :)

Comment: @Pax yup! I am checking for password requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d[^\d\r\n]*\d)(?=.{6,8}$)[A-Z\d]*[!@#$&*_.-][A-Z\d]*[!@#$&*_.-][A-Z\d]*$
```

Note to escape the `\-` in the character class or place it at the start or end. Else it would denote a range.

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char A-Z
- `(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d[^\d\r\n]*\d)` Positive lookahead, assert 2 digits
- `(?=.{6,8}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 6 - 8 characters in total
- `[A-Z\d]*[!@#$&*_.-][A-Z\d]*[!@#$&*_.-][A-Z\d]*` Match 2 "special" characters
- `$` End of string (Or use `\Z` if there can no newline following)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UBucd5/1)

Comment: This is perfect! Only problem is it doesn't match if I have any lowercase characters in the string. Like for example the string "A00!$a" is supposed to match. Do you know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: @SegmentationFault You can add a-z to the matching character class, see https://regex101.com/r/5zbejo/1

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work for you in python

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+,.\\\/;':\"-].*[!@#$%^&*()_+,.\\\/;':\"-]).{6,8}$
```

Here is the test run in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iE4Q6F/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! except for a few things: 1. I just changed the end to .{6,8} (to allow lenghts between 6 and 8). 2. This expression requires that I have atleast one small character, which isnt part of the requirements. But this a great start I can probably figure it out! thanks!

Comment: Also I just noticed one more thing, it lets me put in as many special chars as I want whereas its only asking for exactly 2

Comment: @Segmentation Fault: Be aware that matches [A12!!*$@](https://regex101.com/r/iE4Q6F/5), more than 2 special characters.